# Print react native text and QR generated

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

Hello I need to generate a PDF o HTML view to print a document from an Android device. So I started to use `Print from 'expo-print'`.
I can make this

```
Print.printAsync({
  html: "<h3>Hello World</h3>"
});
```

And works just fine. But I want to generate and include a QR code inside that HTML, I wanted to use `react-native-qrcode` but I don't know how to include it inside that.

clarification: the QR code needs to be created without connection too

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across the same problem and here's my solution.

I use [react-native-qrcode-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg) because it has a *getRef* props for you to further work with the QR data.
Below, you can find my rough implementation (My main code is on another computer). You can further customize it to hide QRCode component or using Redux to store QRData but it should work fine.

```
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

...

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { qrData: "" }
}

componentDidMount () {
  this.getDataURL(); // => Calling this in here to make sure the QRCode component did mount
}

... more code ...
print = () => {
  Print.printAsync({
    html: `
       <h3>Hello World</h3>
       <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.qrData}"/>
     `
  });
}
...

getDataURL() {
  this.svg.toDataURL(this.callback);
}
callback(dataURL) {
  this.setState({qrData: dataURL});
}
render() {
  return (
    <QRCode
      value="Just some string value"
      getRef={(c) => (this.svg = c)}
    />
    <Button title="Print QR to HTML" onPress={this.print} />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm shocked this doesn't have more upvotes. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rn-qr-generator` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-qr-generator). You need to pass `value` to the lib and it will return you `uri` and `base64` data of the generated QRCode

```
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';

componentDidMount() {
    RNQRGenerator.generate({
      value: 'otpauth://totp/Example:alice@google.com?secret=JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP&issuer=Example', // required
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      base64: false, // default 'false'
      backgroundColor: 'black', // default 'white'
      color: 'white', // default 'black'
    })
      .then(response => {
        const { uri, width, height, base64 } = response;
        this.setState({ imageUri: uri });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('Cannot create QR code', error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the html code can be printed, it appears that the code used in html can be used. You will be able to use an `img` tag.

```js
const htmlcode = '<html>'
    + '<head>'
    + '<title>Testing QR code</title>'
    + '</head>'
    + '<body>'
    +  '<img id='barcode' src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" alt="" title="HELLO" width="50" height="50" />'
    + '</body>'
    + '</html>';
...
Print.printAsync({
  html: htmlcode
});
```

---

Additional answers due to edited questions:

If you want to use `QRCODE`, you can't solve it with the module you want to use. Instead, you can solve this through '`React-native-web`.' I will attach the link to the [official document of `Expo`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/running-in-the-browser/) for the **web setup**. Once the setup is complete, use the existing app development method. However, the `QRcode` module does not currently work on the `Web`. The solution to this problem is to set `QRCODE` as an image file path, not as a web path in my first answer, and to show it when it's offline.

**QRcode Example**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode';

import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
  state = {
    text: 'testQRcode',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <QRCode
          value={this.state.text}
          size={200}
          bgColor='purple'
          fgColor='black'/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },

    input: {
        height: 40,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        margin: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 5,
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with that is what happen when the user don't have any connection. I need to generate the QR by code and print it.

Comment: @BraianMellor  The problem you wrote in the question is different from what you think.

Comment: why you think that?

Comment: @BraianMellor There is no precondition for offline in your question.

Comment: Now it's added on the question

Comment: @BraianMellor  I modified my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how can you make to add that QR into the Print.printAsync

Comment: Have you tried what I posted on the answer? Must be online, not offline. If you want to go offline, you need to import QRcode into a photo file.